# How to get previous closest number from array in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array from which we need to get closest previous id on click a button,where as I am getting correct value for closest next,but for previous I am getting directly first id instead of previous id.Can anyone please help me,
For closest next I am using (this.arrayVal.find(id => x < id) || {}); which is working fine
here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<button (click) ="getPrev()">Previous Value</button>
```

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
    arrayVal:any;
    currentVal : any;
  title = 'projectchart';
  public array = [{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5}];


  getPrev(x){
     x = 5;
     this.arrayVal= this.array; 
     let number = (this.arrayVal.find(id => id < x) || {});
     console.log(number);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you provide a sample input with expected output?

Comment: If your button is inside a *ngFor, use *ngFor="let item of tems;let i=index, and pass as argument the "index". so, the prev if i>=0 is i--

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. Using the findIndex you cand find the element you clicked on. Then save that index and subtract from it -1 to get the prev item.

```
  getPrev(idToFind) {
    const index = this.array.findIndex((obj: any) => obj.id === idToFind);
    console.log('click index is: ', index);
    if (index !== -1 && index > 0) {
      let number = this.array[index - 1].id;
      console.log('prev id is: ', number);
    } else {
      console.log('no prev id');
    }
  }
```

[Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvw5la?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)